# Parsing JSON using javascript only

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, loops

I tried looking for a similar question, couldn't find anything detailed enough.

I have a an ajax call, which calls a php page and the response is:

```
echo json_encode($cUrl_c->temp_results);
```

Which outputs:

```
{"key":"value", "key2":"value"}
```

The output is being "parsed" using:

```
var json_response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I was looking for a way to iterate through the response, and getting 
the key and value using javascript only.

1. is the returned output considered valid json ?
2. How do I loop through it (no jquery just javascript) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through the items of an object, you normally use a `for..in` loop, which let you access the keys (property names) as well as the property values:

```
for (var key in object) {
    var item = object[key];
}
```

And yes, `{"key":"value", "key2":"value"}` is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes it is considered valid JSON once you parse it with JSON.parse(), as you have. To answer your second question, have a look at [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) from the MDN.

You could use the first example in the doc to find out how to get the keys and values.

**Example 1**

```
var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

function show_props(obj, objName) {
  var result = "";

  for (var prop in obj) {
    result += objName + "." + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + "\n";
  }

  return result;
}

alert(show_props(o, "o")); /* alerts: o.a = 1 o.b = 2 o.c = 3 */
```